# How to Showcase a O365-App properly?

Tags: c#, powershell, office365

Is there a best practice to provide a Demonstration.-Installation for a O365 App?

We wrote a O365 App that we want to "showcase" to potential customers. Therefor our plan would be to create a side collection inside O365, install our app and "let them play". But to do that we need a user that is allowed to access our SiteCollection. I researched the following approaches:

- Anonymous Access: Does not seem to be possible in O365
- Create a Testuser without real access to O365 without Password: Also not possible
- Create a Testuser without real access to O365 that cannot change its password: Again: You can't remove the ability to change the password

Did I get something wrong there or is there another way to achieve what I want?
Is there maybe an option to create a user programatically (CSOM or Powershell)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create user via Powershell quite easily.

First install Azure AD Cmdlets [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj151815.aspx)

Once installed connect to the services via

```
Connect-MsolService
```

Then you can create user like this

```
New-MsolUser -DisplayName "Zinedine Zidane" -FirstName "Zinedine" -LastName "Zidane" -UserPrincipalName "zinedine.zidane@france98.fr" -Password "123Zizou"
```